# else statement need to be added in watson conversation dialog

Tags: watson

Need help for adding else condition if the input answer is not correct.

Please find the screen shot of If statement I have added.

[Sample_Condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjjmj.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Creating a peer node is equivalent to creating an else node.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't put the else because it's just another intent.

So you could just create another node with an IF test corresponding to the ELSE you want to write.

I can't give you the extract but I hope this screenshot will help you.

This is a small test case for a virtual assistant helping you to do simple banking tasks.
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply, Please share the sample file.